# I need to create an employee schedule/appointments program, but I don't know how to set it up

Tags: php, data-structures, mysql

I work for a gym. I am the programmer, its just me, nobody else! Gets really frustrating when there's nobody to bounce conceptual ideas off of.

I'm getting rid of our archaic paper binder systems for tracking appointments and what not.

I've made a lot of things successfully already, now I'm trying to tackle the personal training department.

What I want:

- Trainer information and work schedule
- Appointment booking that can be done by time slot with all available trainers for that time, or by trainer with all available hours for that trainer

What I've tried so far:

- I started with an 'appointments' database, a 'trainers' database, and a 'schedules' database. This became so complicated trying to fit the schedule in that I scrapped it.

Does anyone know know the best way to structure the tables for this and how to sort of make them communicate correctly? I don't need specific code, I just need help understand *how* to make this thing!

Comment: Somethings are better to buy then to build.

Comment: i don't disagree, but if you've ever tried to get out of a gym membership you would know - PROFIT IS KING!!

Comment: Use Outlook or Google Calendar or any other standard calendar application that allows for multiple users/calendars. If profit is king, then you really, really, really shouldn't be reinventing the wheel for the umpteenth time.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: I thought of those tools, but they won't schedule by available hours.  Actually, Outlook can do it by time slot.

Comment: @robz228, the programmer time to implement a program like this will almost certainly cost far more than the price of purchasing a program.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Google Calendar was the first thing i thought of, but it lacks some restrictions etc that i would need to implement.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple i'm assuming with some of the features we would require, there is no ready-made program out there, so some programming group that would likely charge much more than my hourly rate would have to customize it anyways. i've already stated it may be best to find a professionally licensed product but to no avail. that and i already work here anyways haha.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: doesn't every calendar schedule by time slot? And doesn't every multi-user calendar with a scheduling assistant allow for scheduling by available person/hours? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: At my gym each trainer has their own Calendar Book.  If the trainer is not free they just mark it as such.  I would think that Surface 2 instead with Outlook would work wonders.  Your talking about hundreds of programming hours to do something to match your specific needs.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: Google Calendar doesn't, AFAIK.

Comment: @Ramhound: It's not even all that specific.  Outlook can find an available trainer in a time slot.  That's all he really needs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I agree.  Its not like his paper calendar is more advanced then Outlook

Comment: Of course, if that information needs to go somewhere else (like the billing department), it's a whole 'nother ball game.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I have used Google calendar through Google apps for domains, adding multiple users to the domain in question and each user sharing their calendar with others. When adding a calendar event you can bring up a scheduling assistant for inviting others to your meeting. I assume you can do the same without Google apps for domains if the users in question simply share their calendars. Not very familiar with Google's scheduling assistant works though, so you may well be right!

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not a whole different ball game. Simply a matter of programming an Outlook plugin that can interface with the billing system.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: I'd rather brush my teeth with a brillo pad.  Microsoft application API's are not known for their... intuitiveness.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Aww, com'on. Can't be that bad... :) No, intuitive they aren't, but they are pretty well documented and the Outlook Model is one of the best documented and is designed in a pretty consistent manner.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: Anyway, if Google Calendar works like that, then it works just like Outlook.

Comment: @RobertHarvey we have 13 different gym locations, each one cant see eachothers appointments, but the owners/partners can. are permissions etc possible like this in outlook? it isnt hooked into billing clients, but it would calculate pay for trainers. i just brushed off calendars, but i dont really know how indepth they can go

Comment: @robz228: so program an Outlook plugin and start by learning the Outlook Object Model which is pretty well documented on MSDN.

Comment: @MarjanVenema haha, i'm still not convinced outlook would meet my needs.

Comment: You can use an Exchange Server to share the Outlook calendars across all the gymnasiums.  The only catch would be if there's something about the scheduling process that is unique to the gyms. Calendaring is much more complicated than you think it is; writing something from scratch, and doing it right, will be a fairly substantial undertaking, although it can be done.

Comment: And yes, there are permissions in Outlook, but I don't know how deep that well goes.

Comment: What technologies did you use to write the other applications?

Comment: They are webapps on our intranet with php and mysql

Comment: Oh, God.  PHP...

Comment: @RobertHarvey Heh, i don't know why everyone hates it so much!

Comment: Because http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/06/the-php-singularity.html

Comment: This is weird...for a moment it looked like Robert Harvey was robz and accidentally posted under his normal acct. But either he's not, or he's trying to cleverly disguise that he is by having a conversation with himself LOL

Comment: @MikeBrown it gets lonely being the only programmer in the office

Comment: There are scheduling systems out there already. Think of Doctor's Appointments, Car Care, Hair Salons. I'm sure a quick google will find something that matches what you want. If not, I'll build it for you and give you a free perpetual license for the rights to host as SaaS ;)

Comment: @robz228 *"There are only two kinds of languages: the ones people complain about and the ones nobody uses."*  PHP will suit you fine if thats what you are familiar with.  That said, I'd be very suprised if there wasnt a canned solution available for a fraction of the development cost.  Its not like you're the only multi-site gym in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to buy or use something already in existance than to build something from scratch since this software is widely available.  Unless, of course you want to build a better product and sell it to more than 1 gym.  But if this is just for 1 gym or 1 customer, I would go the buy route and set it up for them.

Google "online appointment scheduler" and I am sure you will find something that suits your requirements.

If your set on building something, for the database schema:

Tables

- Trainer
- Customer
- Gym
- Appointment
- Schedule (View)

Definitions

- Trainer - All trainers
- Customer - All customer (trained by trainers)

These two tables could be rolled up to a "Person" table if desired

- Gym - All gyms
- Appointment - Dual purpose (read below)
- Schedule - A view that shows the calender by day, week, month

Appointment is dual purpose.  Trainers go in and schedule appointments at gyms for availability. Customers can search for trainer appointments and then schedule workout appointments based on the trainer appointments.  The schedule is a view of trainer availability versus scheduled customer appointments which can be aggregated by a certain time period.

In this case we are using appointments as a dual purpose to manage trainer availability and customer appointments.  If you think about it, trainer availability can be abstracted to an appointment at a gym, thus the same table (appointment) could be used for both trainers and customers.

Appointment would have relations to gym, trainer, and customer.  If you rolled Trainers and Customers into a person table it could be one relation, but it might be easier to separate then out.  Otherwise, you will need meta data to describe what kind of person it is (Trainer or Customer)

I would also consider data retention here and have an automated job to prune the appointment table.  No need to keep appointment from 6 months ago.  I am not sure of your retention requirements.

Comment: its 13 gyms and its going to communicate with other web apps we already use, which is part of the reason buying one would be a problem. My question is more of like "whats a good database-schema for appointments and schedules"

Comment: OK, I will update answer to reflect schema only

Comment: thanks for this. and especially the explanation. i'll try something out like this

Comment: I would keep two foreign keys on the appointments table: trainer_id, customer_id. An appointment is always exactly 1 trainer, and optionally 1 customer, so trainers have some set of appointment rows (created automatically each week/month based on settings?), and customers get linked to an appointment when they reserve one.

Comment: @Mike I agree, I think it would be easier to track trainer versus customer appointments that way.  I am not sure if the trainer can have more than one customer scheduled at a time, maybe a group session?  If so, then the schema would have to account for that.  I assumed 1 on 1.

Comment: Good point; I assumed 1 on 1 as well.

Comment: I bet their's an existing scheduler that supports integration with your other web apps.  Probably even one that's open source.